# Flutter Dio.get or http.get local ip error

Tags: dart, networking, connection, local

(
Response response = await Dio().get("https://www.google.com.tr/");
statusMesagge = "OK"
)
(
**Response response2 = await Dio().get("http://10.10.10.1/");**

OR

**var response3 = await http.get(url1);**

**same error**

HttpException: **Invalid request method**, uri = http://10.10.10.1/

**Not Working**
)
WHY????

why

HttpException: **Invalid request method**, uri = http://10.10.10.1/